# Как получить переменную JS из HTML страницы

Tags: android, javascript, java, html

Здравствуйте! Пытаюсь получить ссылку изображения, которое показывается на странице. В коде есть js переменная, в которой содержится адрес изображения. Как эту переменную можно получить для дальнейшего использования?

> "http://webuycontent.atwebpages.com/wallbase.html"
> Получить хочу тег "src"

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 30 * 1000);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 30 * 1000);

    httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
    httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    httpGet.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
    //Запрос
    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    InputStream instream = null;
    try {
        instream = response.getEntity().getContent();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Header contentEncoding = response.getFirstHeader("Content-Encoding");
    if ((contentEncoding != null) && contentEncoding.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) {
        try {
            instream = new GZIPInputStream(instream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream, "utf-8"), 8);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.contains("\" src"))
            {
             sb.append(line).append("\n");
        }}
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        instream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String result = sb.toString();

    Log.i("Do id back", " ");

    return result;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    txtUrl.setText(result.toString());
    Log.i("on Post","   ");
}
```

}

Comment: @Garf1eld, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать регулярные выражения или парсер html. Код упростится, его поддержка станет гораздо проще.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант можно предложить и следующий подход:

```
1. Добавить в приложение компонент WebView и загрузить в него необходимый HTML-код с нужного вам URL (или сгенерированном "на лету").

2. Разрешить исполнение JS-кода в компоненте. Добавить в код страницы подключение JS-библиотеки jQuery (на более простого парсинга данных).

3. С помощью jQuery вытащить то, что нужно из страницы. Передать информацию в Java код посредством использования JS-интерфейсов компонента WebView (метод addJavascriptInterface() ).
```

Должен также заметить, что такой подход куда более ресурсоемкий с точки зрения системы, но простой с точки зрения использования. Ресурсоемкость возникает в связи с использованием "тяжелого" визуального компонента WebView.

Comment: Как раз у меня такая история, у меня есть WebView и в нем отображется картинка, по нажатию на нее нужно сохранять

Comment: В таком случае ваше решение - парсинг DOM с помощью jQuery, получение нужных данных и отправка их в Java код через класс интерфейса( о чем я уже писал выше )

Answer (score 0):

Код для конкретно этой страницы:

```
public String getLink(String html)
{
    int start = html.indexOf("'") + 1;
    int end = html.indexOf("'", start);
    return html.substring(start, end);
}
```